# How to use React Navigation with an element inside of a FlatList's Header?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I can navigate perfectly within the renderItem, but when i try within the component that I use in the header when I click it says "undefinded is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

This is how Im trying to navigate within the component thats been passed to the FlatLists's header
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { data: info })}>`

Comment: could you send some more code with header code here ?

Comment: pls provide reproducable code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a hunch, but my guess is the component is being passed for `ListHeaderComponent` instead of a rendered element with the `navigation` prop.

For example:

```
function Parent(props) {
  // Here the FlatList will render the header as <MyHeader /> with no props
  // If this.props.navigation is called in MyHeader it will be undefined
  return (
    <FlatList ListHeaderComponent={MyHeader} ... />
  );
}
```

vs

```
function Parent(props) {
  // here MyHeader is rendered as an element first, passing through
  // the necessary navigation prop
  const headerElement = (<MyHeader navigation={props.navigation} />);
  return (
    <FlatList ListHeaderComponent={headerElement} ... />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I passed through the navigation prop to the ListHeaderComponent, and it works, because the rendered element gave me some other problems

This is how i did it

```
return(
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    ListHeaderComponent={
                        <>
                            <Header navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
                        </>
                    }
                    style={styles.scrollView}
                    numColumns='2'
                    columnWrapperStyle={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}
                    data={ex}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
```